# Laravel custom validation on registration form

Tags: php, laravel

I'm currently struggling with a bit of validation on a registration form.

Basically when a user registers it will check if the unique code they have entered is valid and if not doesn't let them sign up.

But in my codes table which this reads from I also have an expiry date on the code.

I need to do another check after it is deemed valid that the expiry date hasn't passed, in other words it is not greater than now.

I think you can do this in the validator but I'm struggling a bit with the syntax and not sure where it should go. Here is my code:

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{

    return Validator::make($data, [
        'code' => 'required|exists:codes',
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'date_of_birth' => 'required|date',
        'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
        'accept_terms' => 'required|accepted',
    ]);
}

/**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return User
 */
protected function create(array $data)
{   
    Code::where('code', $data['code'])->increment('uses');

    $data['code_id'] = Code::where('code', $data['code'])->value('id');

    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'date_of_birth' => $data['date_of_birth'],
        'accept_terms' => $data['accept_terms'],
        'code' => $data['code'],
        'code_id' => $data['code_id'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: Sorry I should of made this clear, I'm using Laravel 5.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as you're using Laravel v5.3.18 (or higher) you can use the `Rule` Class to save you having to define a custom rule.

This:

```
'code' => 'required|exists:codes',
```

Can be replaced with:

```
'code' => [
    'required',
    Rule::exists('codes')->where(function ($query) {
        $query->where('expiry_date', '>=', Carbon::now());
    }),
],
```

(the above is assuming `expiry_date` is the actual name of the column in your db table).

Documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#rule-exists

Just make sure you import those facades.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot this is exactly what I was looking for but couldn't get the syntax right. It seems to be throwing an error though `FatalThrowableError in RegisterController.php line 56:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'Carbon' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ')'`

Comment: @user6073700 As I said, you need to make sure to include the Facades otherwise change it to `Carbon\Carbon::now()`

Comment: Missing a `,` before `Carbon`

Comment: @user6073700 I've updated my answer. There was a missing `,`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, how would I differentiate between the code being invalid and it being expired in terms of showing error messages to the user? Does this code do that anyway?

Comment: @user6073700 No, it won't do (or at least I'm pretty sure it doesn't). If you want to show a different message you can either create a separate rule to check expiration and go back to your origin rule `exists:codes` as well or manually check in the controller method if it has expired and pass through a custom error message : https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#custom-error-messages.

Answer (score 3):

You can [create custom validation rule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#custom-validation-rules). Create service provider and register it. Then add something like this:

```
Validator::extend('is_code_valid', function($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
    $code = Code::where('code', $value)->where('date', '>', Carbon::now())->first();
    return !$code->isEmpty(); // Pass if valid code exists in DB.
});
```

And then use it:

```
'code' => 'required|is_code_valid',
```