# How to apply an middleware on ::auth()?

Tags: php, laravel

Here is my code in the `routes.php` file:

```
Route::auth();
```

Now I need to put a middleware on the way of that route. Something like this:

```
Route::auth()->middleware('setLang');
```

But in this case, it throws this error:

> FatalErrorException in routes.php line 43:
>   Call to a member function middleware() on null

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make it work, you first need to [register middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/middleware#registering-middleware).

After that use `group()` method to set `middleware` property:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'setLang'], function () {
    Route::auth();
});
```

If you still get `Class not found` error, try to run `composer dumpauto` command.

Comment: @AmitGupta, are you kidding me? You've copied & pasted my code three times this week. I saw you also copied Joseph Silber's code as well. After you I told you about this, you've told you didn't copy it. Then you've deleted post. You don't know that, but guys with rating like `> 10000` still can see deleted posts. But it seems you don't care about your reputation while trying to do nasty stuff to raise your rating. Now you're trying to tell me I'm copying your code, while the code in the only way to do what OP is asking and it's from docs with just middleware name changed.

Comment: And here's your deleted post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40344687/laravel-custom-validation-on-registration-form/40344861#40344861

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin this what I am saying when the code is the only way to do same task, you always think I am coping.

Comment: @AmitGupta, I've posted the link, so people could see what actual copy&pasting look like and so they could have their own opinion.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin and people can also see what you have done in above answer.

Comment: You mean when @RAUSHAN KUMAR posted this code. Then you've posted exactly the same answer, then I've wrote extended answer with link to the middleware registering docs (which was the actual problem because of `Class not found` error) and then you've added link to the same registering middleware doc too? Well, ok.

Answer (score 2):

you should use your middleware in the route group having your routes inside it as

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'setLang'], function () {
    Route::auth();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'setLang'], function () {
  Route::auth();
});
```

And remember to register your middleware.
[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/middleware#registering-middleware)

Comment: Now it throws this error: `ReflectionException in Container.php line 734:
Class setLang does not exist`. any idea?